# What is the radius unit of geom.Circle?

Tags: openlayers-3

I have checked this:
   http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/apidoc/ol.geom.Circle.html
   and can't find any description about radius's unit(meter,mail,or??),have I missed something?and where can I find it?
  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

depending on the projection you use. If it is in meters then radius shall be supplied as meters. To verify the units of your projection, use the `getUnits()` method of the projection you use.